# Segmentation Error with a linked list while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having trouble with a project I am working on for class.  I am particularly having trouble with recursively printing a linked list of `spheres`.  Whenever the program runs over the particular part:

```
ss=ss->next;
```

there is a `Segmentation fault: 11`. What could the problem be? 
(Note: I've included the necessary `structs`sphere`and`sphere_list`, and left out`rgb`and`vec` so as to not clutter up the code.)

```
typedef struct sphere {
  vec *center;
  double radius;
  rgb *color;
} sphere;

typedef struct sphere_list sphere_list;
/* convention: NULL is the empty sphere list */
struct sphere_list {
  sphere *s;
  sphere_list *next;
};

void sl_print(sphere_list *ss)
{ 
if(ss==NULL)
  printf("SPHERE LIST EMPTY\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("SPHERE LIST:\n");
int i=1;
while(ss->s!=NULL){
  printf("\t%d ", i);
  sphere_print(ss->s);
  if(ss->next==NULL){
    printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    return;
    }
  ss=ss->next;
  i++;
  }
  printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
  return;
}
```

Comment: `if(ss==NULL)`. is there a corresponding `else`??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 void sl_print(sphere_list *ss)
 { 
  if(ss==NULL){
   printf("SPHERE LIST EMPTY\n");
   printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
   printf("SPHERE LIST:\n");
   return ;
  }
  int i=1;
  while(ss != NULL){
   printf("\t%d ", i);
   sphere_print(ss->s);
   ss=ss->next;
   i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made an error in your loop conditions. You have to test next value, because this is why you move on on sphere_list.

```
void sl_print(sphere_list *ss)
{
sphere_list *tmp = ss;

if(ss==NULL)
  printf("SPHERE LIST EMPTY\n");
  printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
  printf("SPHERE LIST:\n");
  int i=1;
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    printf("\t%d ", i);
    if (tmp->s != NULL)
      sphere_print(tmp->s);
    if(tmp->next==NULL){
        printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    return;
    }
    tmp=tmp->next;
    i++;
  }
  printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
  return;
}
```

Modified*

Comment: the statement `while(ss->next != NULL)` is not printing the last node of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct sphere_list {
sphere *s;
sphere_list *next;
};
```

have you allocated space for `sphere *s` and made the pointer point to valid memory?, I would have done this, just a suggestion.

```
typedef struct sphere {
vec *center;
double radius;
rgb *color;
//included the pointer in the struct//
struct sphere *next
} sphere;
```

Also, typedef structs are not favoured by most people.makes the code harder to read.